# How to post a file content with wget in a post variable?

Tags: php, wget

I have a very simple php script :

```
<?
  $received:file = $_POST['file'];
  // do something with it
?>
```

I'm trying to post the content of a local file (unix) using wget.

```
wget --post-data='operation=upload' --post-file myfile
```

seems to post but don't attach to any 'field'.

How can I do that ?

Comment: If you read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html), you can see it says that `wget` doesn't support file upload. Use something else like `curl` instead. Also `--post-data` and `--post-file` can't co-exist. Only one of them should be specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post request with Wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699666/post-request-with-wget)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need `wget`? Actually upon reading the wget man page ... wget can't do what you want it to do.

You can use `curl`

```
curl -F"operation=upload" -F"file=@myfile" http://localhost:9000/index.php
```

Get the file with:

```
<?php
$uploadfile = '/tmp/' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
$content = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
?>
```

Comment: right; i didn't think of curl ... i've tried; but it doesn't seem to post the file.

Comment: where does the content of the file get posted ? in a post variable ?

Comment: Well myfile must exist in your current directory ... if you still think it doesn't work, you could use `ngrep` to listen to the network request ... ex. ngrep -d lo -c 120 port 9000

Comment: Actually ... Tony said it right ... it gets posted into $_FILES ... see http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php ... so $_FILES['file'] is what you're looking for.

Comment: For multiple files, use: -F"file1=@myfile1" -F"file2=@myfile2" and so on. (file1, file2 can be anything. You will read it as: $_FILES["file1"] and $_FILES["file2"] or just do a foreach($_FILES ...)

Comment: For multiple POST values use: -F"key1=value" -F"key2=value" and so on.