# How to get the name of a file sent to a php://input via wget post-file

Tags: php, post

I wrote a script that receives an image file through `file_get_contents('php://input')` and does some other magic. The file is sent from a client using the `wget post-file=blahblah.blah` command and it's all working fine.

The issue that I have is that I need to use the name of the received image file as a string for processing purposes and `file_get_contents()` gives me the content of the file but not the name of it.
Would anyone know how I can get the name?

Any answer that can put me in the right direction would be well appreciated.

Comment: The filename `wget` reads to get the data for `--post-file` is not included in the HTTP request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post a file content with wget in a post variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661759/how-to-post-a-file-content-with-wget-in-a-post-variable)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not at all the same question as the one you're mentioning above  mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `--post-file` option to `wget` sends the contents of the file as a raw POST request; it does not treat it as a file upload, so the name of the file is not transmitted. Per the `wget` manual page:

> `--post-data=string`
>
> `--post-file=file`
>
> Use POST as the method for all HTTP requests and send the specified
>   data in the request body.  `--post-data` sends string as data,
>   whereas `--post-file` sends the contents of file.  Other than that,
>   they work in exactly the same way. In particular, they both expect
>   content of the form `"key1=value1&key2=value2"`, with percent-
>   encoding for special characters; the only difference is that one
>   expects its content as a command-line parameter and the other
>   accepts its content from a file. **In particular, `--post-file` is not
>   for transmitting files as form attachments: those must appear as
>   `"key=value"` data (with appropriate percent-coding) just like
>   everything else.**

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to go about getting the file name. I believe the classic way would be using url parameters ( POST your file to example.com/your-script.php?name=some-file-name-here ) but an alternative and possibly cleaner way would be using custom http headers: 'X-Filename: your-file-name'.

```
wget --header "X-Filename: your-file-name" --post-file /your/file
```

Then in PHP check for the headers ( using apache_request_headers() for example ).

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built in superglobal variable `$_FILES`, it works similar to `$_POST`.

```
$_FILES['/*the html object name goes here*/']['name']
```

The `['name']` part of the array returns the actual name of the file uploaded from the html object name.

So to clarify, if your html was `<input type="file" name="screenshot" />`
your PHP would be `$name = $_FILE['screenshot']['name']`

`$name` now stores the string that holds the name of the file.